# Java: How to put two events in the same method

Tags: java

I'm having a problem with trying to get the mousePressed() mouse event and the Java paint() graphics in the same method (I have tried to simplify to code as much as possible [Java 7+]).

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.Math.*;

public class JFrameClick extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    //Main method in here
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
    //handle Java 2 graphics 
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    //Handle mouse press
    }

//Other methods here

}
```

How would I go about getting the paint function to fire off every time the mousePressed() method gets executed. I have tried this code down here and it doesn't work.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.Math.*;

public class JFrameClick extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
   //Main method in here
   }

   public void paint(Graphics g, MouseEvent e){
   mousePressed(e);
   //handle Java 2 graphics
   }

   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
   //Handle mouse press
   }

//Other methods here

}

//This doesn't work vice versa either
```

Thanks.

Comment: Call `repaint()` inside mousePressed?

Comment: Thanks, repaint worked!

Comment: Also, as a side note, I believe it is common practice to override the `paintComponent` method instead of just `paint`. Also don't forget to call `super.repaint()` inside whatever method you do override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To request Swing to repaint your widget, you can use the `repaint() method`, as in:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // do other stuff

    repaint();
}
```

Swing will call your `paint` method as soon as possible.

Painting at any other time (other than when Swing calls your `paint` method) - including calling `paint` yourself - is not recommended and often leads to graphical glitches.

Your attempted solution tells me that you do not have a good understanding of methods, but that is outside the scope of this question.